# Is it possible to copy a server image from AWS EC2 and run it in Virtual Box?

Tags: mac-osx, amazon-ec2, virtualbox, amazon-web-services

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to obtain a copy of Amazon Linux for use outside AWS](https://serverfault.com/questions/303364/is-it-possible-to-obtain-a-copy-of-amazon-linux-for-use-outside-aws)

Does anyone know if it's possible to copy an Amazon Web Services EC2 image of a server back to a local machine and run it in Virtual Box? From research I can see that it's possible to do the reverse, take a Virtual Box image and migrate it to AWS, but I'm not sure if you can copy a live server setup to Virtual Box for development.

I've recently taken over a project being hosted on AWS EC2. The project requires linux and a fair bit of custom configuration to run, so this seamed the best way to setup a dev environment (our development machines are Macs).

Answer (score 1):

According to this answer: [Is it possible to obtain a copy of Amazon Linux for use outside AWS](https://serverfault.com/questions/303364/is-it-possible-to-obtain-a-copy-of-amazon-linux-for-use-outside-aws)

You can use `ec2-unbundle` to download any AMI you control.

Answer (score 0):

Last time I checked, there wasn't a way to port them out - can you run DEV using a cloned machine in AWS?

Answer (score 0):

You might take a look at VMware Converter - http://www.vmware.com/products/converter/. It has the ability to convert live running systems into VMware format, which VirtualBox can mount. The resulting image may require some driver updates for VirtualBox optimizations.